# Error message with tabularx

Tags: errors, tabularx

I am very very very new to LaTeX, like I just started understanding what is does yesterday. I am using Stata 15 and wanted to make nice tables.

There is a problem with the code below. I keep getting the error message:

```
159: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 
l.159 \end{tabularx}
```

Also, How can I get this all on one page? All and any help is much appreicated.

MY CODE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Table 3. Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods} \par \vspace{2ex}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {12cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y @{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\
& Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
\midrule 

\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 43.5 & 9.67 & 25 & 61 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.82 & 0.85 & 2.19 & 5.35 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 216 & 84.0 & 79 &  354 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 19.0 & 7.37 & 6.93 & 31.1 \\
All Food Chances & 365.5 & 121.2 & 159 &  575 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 32.1 & 10.6 & 14.0 & 50.5 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Morrisania/East Tremont}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 24.8 & 6.46 & 13 & 34 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.09 & 0.80 & 1.62 & 4.23 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 210.8 & 76.4 & 98 &  345 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 26.3 & 9.52 & 12.2 & 43.0 \\
All Food Chances & 325.7 & 107.6 &  163 &  517 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 40.6 & 13.4 & 20.3 & 64.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Williamsburg/Greenpoint}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 53.2 & 9.10 & 35 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 4.37 & 0.75 & 2.88 & 5.59 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 279.5 & 59.5 &  166 &  359 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.0 & 4.88 & 13.6 & 29.5 \\
All Food Chances & 508.9 & 124.4 &  290 &  711 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 41.8 & 10.2 & 23.8 & 58.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Bedford Stuyvesant}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 14.3 & 3.23 &  9 & 22 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 1.90 & 0.43 & 1.20 & 2.93 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 175.8 & 50.8 & 67 &  252 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.4 & 6.77 & 8.92 & 33.6 \\
All Food Chances & 260.6 & 70.4 &  110 &  366 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 34.7 & 9.37 & 14.6 & 48.7 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Bushwick}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.8 & 2.50 & 18 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 4.21 & 0.48 & 3.47 & 5.21 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 168.4 & 53.7 & 82 &  259 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 32.5 & 10.4 & 15.8 & 50.0 \\
All Food Chances &  258 & 81.5 &  121 &  398 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 49.8 & 15.7 & 23.4 & 76.8 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Sunset Park}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 25.7 & 5.39 & 17 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 2.68 & 0.56 & 1.77 & 3.65 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 246.0 & 73.4 &  125 &  369 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 25.7 & 7.66 & 13.0 & 38.5 \\
All Food Chances & 404.9 & 117.9 &  197 &  626 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 42.3 & 12.3 & 20.6 & 65.3 \\
\midrule 

\emph{North Crown Heights/Prospect Heights}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 38.5 & 6.08 & 24 & 51 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 9.30 & 1.47 & 5.79 & 12.3 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 159.2 & 40.1 & 82 &  222 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 38.4 & 9.68 & 19.8 & 53.6 \\
All Food Chances & 298.2 & 68.8 &  159 &  412 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 72.0 & 16.6 & 38.4 & 99.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{South Crown Heights}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 29.9 & 4.41 & 21 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 7.20 & 1.06 & 5.07 & 8.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 125.4 & 24.1 & 76 &  167 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 30.3 & 5.81 & 18.3 & 40.3 \\
All Food Chances & 229.9 & 45.6 &  130 &  309 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 55.5 & 11.0 & 31.4 & 74.6 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Brownsville/Ocean Hill}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 18.5 & 4.01 &  8 & 23 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.75 & 0.81 & 1.63 & 4.67 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 116.3 & 38.8 & 43 &  183 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.6 & 7.88 & 8.74 & 37.2 \\
All Food Chances & 185.8 & 53.2 & 80 &  277 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 37.8 & 10.8 & 16.3 & 56.3 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Lower East Side/Chinatown}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 54.4 & 6.15 & 41 & 65 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 12.4 & 1.40 & 9.31 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 297.3 & 73.4 &  172 &  406 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 67.5 & 16.7 & 39.1 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances & 767.0 & 179.9 &  478 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 174.2 & 40.9 & 108.6 & 250.5 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Morningside Heights/Hamilton Heights}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.1 & 2.94 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 5.70 & 0.76 & 4.12 & 6.95 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 124.4 & 38.4 & 60 &  188 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 32.0 & 9.88 & 15.4 & 48.4 \\
All Food Chances & 250.3 & 66.7 &  136 &  363 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 64.4 & 17.2 & 35.0 & 93.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Central Harlem}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.2 & 3.11 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 6.13 & 0.86 & 4.41 & 7.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 136.8 & 44.7 & 68 &  207 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 37.7 & 12.3 & 18.8 & 57.1 \\
All Food Chances & 249.0 & 71.2 &  130 &  374 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 68.7 & 19.6 & 35.9 & 103.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{East Harlem}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.9 & 2.79 & 17 & 26 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.52 & 0.45 & 2.73 & 4.18 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 147.1 & 53.5 & 57 &  236 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.7 & 8.60 & 9.17 & 38.0 \\
All Food Chances & 249.5 & 79.5 &  114 &  392 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 40.1 & 12.8 & 18.3 & 63.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Washington Heights/Inwood}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 40.3 & 5.06 & 32 & 48 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 5.56 & 0.70 & 4.41 & 6.62 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 269.3 & 78.5 &  140 &  388 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 37.1 & 10.8 & 19.3 & 53.5 \\
All Food Chances & 453.3 & 114.9 &  268 &  646 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 62.5 & 15.8 & 37.0 & 89.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Astoria}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 48.8 & 7.19 & 34 & 58 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.04 & 0.45 & 2.12 & 3.61 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances &  338 & 72.8 &  202 &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 21.0 & 4.53 & 12.6 & 27.9 \\
All Food Chances & 620.0 & 140.9 &  352 &  858 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 38.6 & 8.78 & 21.9 & 53.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Total}  \\
Healthy Food Chances & 32.0 & 14.0 &  8 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 5.11 & 2.81 & 1.20 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 200.7 & 90.3 & 43 &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 30.7 & 14.7 & 6.93 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances & 361.8 & 187.5 & 80 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 57.0 & 37.6 & 14.0 & 250.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\par\smallskip\noindent\parbox{12cm}{\raggedright \scriptsize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.}
\normalsize
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: delete line `&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\ ` (which require 9 columns, but you define only 7. also this line is empty, so it is not needed in table. welcome to tex.se! However, your table has some other issues. it is to huge for placement ion one page, etc. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I would never use tabularx for tables of figures (and I wrote it) it is designed to control line breaking of paragraphs of text within tables, and you have no such entries.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I'm so grateful. I have been looking online and trying to teach myself from examples but its not going so well...I'm using Stata's command tabout to create a tex file which i then typeset in TeXShop. David, if I do not use tabularx to create a table then can you please suggest what I should be doing and maybe an example I can follow?

Answer (score 5):

as i mentioned in my comment, your table has more issues as mentioned error (which is solved by my comment):

- table is to huge that can be fit on one page, actually it is long two and half page, so you need `longtable` or `ltablex` packages for it
- rows are not consistent typed; also in case if you have except the first column all other empty, you should always typed all ampersands which define columns
- for numbers in i would use `S` column type

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{booktabs, longtable} % <---

  \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}    % <---
  \usepackage{siunitx}              % <--- 
  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{@{} l *{5}{S[table-format=4.2]} @{}}
  \caption{Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods}
  \label{tab:longtable}                                               \\
      \toprule
      & {Mean}    &   {Std. Dev.} &   {Min}   &   {Max}               \\
      \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \caption{Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods (cont.)}                                              \\
      \toprule
      & {Mean}    &   {Std. Dev.} &   {Min}   &   {Max}               \\
      \midrule
  \endhead
      \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape{continue on the next page}}
  \endfoot
      \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.}
      \normalsize
  \endlastfoot
  % table body
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}}                   \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 43.5  & 9.67  & 25    & 61    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 3.82  & 0.85  & 2.19  & 5.35  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 216   & 84.0  & 79    &  354  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 19.0  & 7.37  & 6.93  & 31.1  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 365.5 & 121.2 & 159   &  575  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 32.1  & 10.6  & 14.0  & 50.5  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Morrisania/East Tremont}}                  \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 24.8  & 6.46  & 13    & 34    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 3.09  & 0.80  & 1.62  & 4.23  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 210.8 & 76.4  & 98    &  345  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 26.3  & 9.52  & 12.2 & 43.0   \\
  All Food Chances                    & 325.7 & 107.6 &  163 &  517   \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 40.6  & 13.4  & 20.3 & 64.4   \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Williamsburg/Greenpoint}}                  \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 53.2  & 9.10  & 35    & 68    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 4.37  & 0.75  & 2.88  & 5.59  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 279.5 & 59.5  &  166  &  359  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 23.0  & 4.88  & 13.6  & 29.5  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 508.9 & 124.4 &  290  &  711  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 41.8  & 10.2  & 23.8  & 58.4  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Bedford Stuyvesant}}                       \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 14.3  & 3.23  &  9    & 22    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 1.90  & 0.43  & 1.20  & 2.93  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 175.8 & 50.8  & 67    &  252  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 23.4  & 6.77  & 8.92  & 33.6  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 260.6 & 70.4  &  110  &  366  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 34.7  & 9.37  & 14.6  & 48.7  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Bushwick}}                                 \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 21.8  & 2.50  & 18    & 27    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 4.21  & 0.48  & 3.47  & 5.21  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 168.4 & 53.7  & 82    &  259  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 32.5  & 10.4  & 15.8  & 50.0  \\
  All Food Chances                    &  258  & 81.5  &  121  &  398  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 49.8  & 15.7  & 23.4  & 76.8  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Sunset Park}}                              \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 25.7  & 5.39  & 17    & 35    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 2.68  & 0.56  & 1.77  & 3.65  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 246.0 & 73.4  &  125  &  369  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 25.7  & 7.66  & 13.0  & 38.5  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 404.9 & 117.9 &  197  &  626  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 42.3  & 12.3  & 20.6  & 65.3  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{North Crown Heights/Prospect Heights}}     \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 38.5  & 6.08  & 24    & 51    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 9.30  & 1.47  & 5.79  & 12.3  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 159.2 & 40.1  & 82    &  222  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 38.4  & 9.68  & 19.8  & 53.6  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 298.2 & 68.8  &  159  &  412  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 72.0  & 16.6  & 38.4  & 99.4  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{South Crown Heights}}                      \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 29.9  & 4.41  & 21    & 35    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 7.20  & 1.06  & 5.07  & 8.45  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 125.4 & 24.1  & 76    &  167  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 30.3  & 5.81  & 18.3  & 40.3  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 229.9 & 45.6  &  130  &  309  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 55.5  & 11.0  & 31.4  & 74.6  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Brownsville/Ocean Hill}}                   \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 18.5  & 4.01  &  8    & 23    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 3.75  & 0.81  & 1.63  & 4.67  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 116.3 & 38.8  & 43    &  183  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 23.6  & 7.88  & 8.74  & 37.2  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 185.8 & 53.2  & 80    &  277  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 37.8  & 10.8  & 16.3  & 56.3  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Lower East Side/Chinatown}}                \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 54.4  & 6.15  & 41    & 65    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 12.4  & 1.40  & 9.31  & 14.8  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 297.3 & 73.4  &  172  &  406  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 67.5  & 16.7  & 39.1  & 92.2  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 767.0 & 179.9 &  478  & 1103  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 174.2 & 40.9  & 108.6 & 250.5 \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Morningside Heights/Hamilton Heights}}     \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 22.1  & 2.94  & 16    & 27    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 5.70  & 0.76  & 4.12  & 6.95  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 124.4 & 38.4  & 60    &  188  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 32.0  & 9.88  & 15.4  & 48.4  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 250.3 & 66.7  &  136  &  363  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 64.4  & 17.2  & 35.0  & 93.4  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Central Harlem}}                           \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 22.2  & 3.11  & 16    & 27    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 6.13  & 0.86  & 4.41  & 7.45  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 136.8 & 44.7  & 68    &  207  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 37.7  & 12.3  & 18.8  & 57.1  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 249.0 & 71.2  &  130  &  374  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 68.7  & 19.6  & 35.9  & 103.1 \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{East Harlem}}                              \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 21.9  & 2.79  & 17    & 26    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 3.52  & 0.45  & 2.73  & 4.18  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 147.1 & 53.5  & 57    &  236  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 23.7  & 8.60  & 9.17  & 38.0  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 249.5 & 79.5  &  114  &  392  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 40.1  & 12.8  & 18.3  & 63.1  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Washington Heights/Inwood}}                \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 40.3  & 5.06  & 32    & 48    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 5.56  & 0.70  & 4.41  & 6.62  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 269.3 & 78.5  &  140  &  388  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 37.1  & 10.8  & 19.3  & 53.5  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 453.3 & 114.9 &  268  &  646  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 62.5  & 15.8  & 37.0  & 89.1  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Astoria}}                                  \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 48.8  & 7.19  & 34    & 58    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 3.04  & 0.45  & 2.12  & 3.61  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              &  338  & 72.8  &  202  &  448  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 21.0  & 4.53  & 12.6  & 27.9  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 620.0 & 140.9 &  352  &  858  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 38.6  & 8.78  & 21.9  & 53.4  \\
  \midrule

  \multicolumn{5}{l}{\emph{Total}}                                    \\
  Healthy Food Chances                & 32.0  & 14.0  &  8    & 68    \\
  Healthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}  & 5.11  & 2.81  & 1.20  & 14.8  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances              & 200.7 & 90.3  & 43    &  448  \\
  Unhealthy Food Chances per \si{km^2}& 30.7  & 14.7  & 6.93  & 92.2  \\
  All Food Chances                    & 361.8 & 187.5 & 80    & 1103  \\
  All Food Chances per \si{km^2}      & 57.0  & 37.6  & 14.0  & 250.5 \\
      \end{longtable}
  \end{document}
  ```

which gives:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion. I have replaced `tabularx` by `longtable` as you a) don't need automatic line breaks of paragraphs and b) have a table that is a lot longer than a single page. Additionally, I have used the `caption` comand for the caption (and used the `caption` package in order to control the font of the caption). Lastly, I have also added the missing two columns. If you don't need more columns, you can replace `\begin{longtable}{@{} l rrrrrrrr@{}}` by `\begin{longtable}{@{} l rrrr@{}}` and `&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\` by `&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)}\\`. I have also replaced `km2` by `\squarekilometre` from the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[load=abbr]{siunitx}
\begin{document}


{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{} l rrrrrrrr@{}}
\caption{Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods}\\
\toprule
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\
& Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\
& Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
\midrule 
\endhead
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\scriptsize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.}
\endlastfoot

\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 43.5 & 9.67 & 25 & 61 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 3.82 & 0.85 & 2.19 & 5.35 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 216 & 84.0 & 79 &  354 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 19.0 & 7.37 & 6.93 & 31.1 \\
All Food Chances & 365.5 & 121.2 & 159 &  575 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 32.1 & 10.6 & 14.0 & 50.5 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Morrisania/East Tremont}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 24.8 & 6.46 & 13 & 34 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 3.09 & 0.80 & 1.62 & 4.23 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 210.8 & 76.4 & 98 &  345 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 26.3 & 9.52 & 12.2 & 43.0 \\
All Food Chances & 325.7 & 107.6 &  163 &  517 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 40.6 & 13.4 & 20.3 & 64.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Williamsburg/Greenpoint}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 53.2 & 9.10 & 35 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 4.37 & 0.75 & 2.88 & 5.59 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 279.5 & 59.5 &  166 &  359 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 23.0 & 4.88 & 13.6 & 29.5 \\
All Food Chances & 508.9 & 124.4 &  290 &  711 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 41.8 & 10.2 & 23.8 & 58.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Bedford Stuyvesant}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 14.3 & 3.23 &  9 & 22 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 1.90 & 0.43 & 1.20 & 2.93 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 175.8 & 50.8 & 67 &  252 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 23.4 & 6.77 & 8.92 & 33.6 \\
All Food Chances & 260.6 & 70.4 &  110 &  366 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 34.7 & 9.37 & 14.6 & 48.7 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Bushwick}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 21.8 & 2.50 & 18 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 4.21 & 0.48 & 3.47 & 5.21 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 168.4 & 53.7 & 82 &  259 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 32.5 & 10.4 & 15.8 & 50.0 \\
All Food Chances &  258 & 81.5 &  121 &  398 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 49.8 & 15.7 & 23.4 & 76.8 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Sunset Park}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 25.7 & 5.39 & 17 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 2.68 & 0.56 & 1.77 & 3.65 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 246.0 & 73.4 &  125 &  369 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 25.7 & 7.66 & 13.0 & 38.5 \\
All Food Chances & 404.9 & 117.9 &  197 &  626 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 42.3 & 12.3 & 20.6 & 65.3 \\
\midrule 

\emph{North Crown Heights/Prospect Heights}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 38.5 & 6.08 & 24 & 51 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 9.30 & 1.47 & 5.79 & 12.3 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 159.2 & 40.1 & 82 &  222 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 38.4 & 9.68 & 19.8 & 53.6 \\
All Food Chances & 298.2 & 68.8 &  159 &  412 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 72.0 & 16.6 & 38.4 & 99.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{South Crown Heights}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 29.9 & 4.41 & 21 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 7.20 & 1.06 & 5.07 & 8.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 125.4 & 24.1 & 76 &  167 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 30.3 & 5.81 & 18.3 & 40.3 \\
All Food Chances & 229.9 & 45.6 &  130 &  309 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 55.5 & 11.0 & 31.4 & 74.6 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Brownsville/Ocean Hill}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 18.5 & 4.01 &  8 & 23 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 3.75 & 0.81 & 1.63 & 4.67 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 116.3 & 38.8 & 43 &  183 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 23.6 & 7.88 & 8.74 & 37.2 \\
All Food Chances & 185.8 & 53.2 & 80 &  277 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 37.8 & 10.8 & 16.3 & 56.3 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Lower East Side/Chinatown}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 54.4 & 6.15 & 41 & 65 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 12.4 & 1.40 & 9.31 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 297.3 & 73.4 &  172 &  406 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 67.5 & 16.7 & 39.1 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances & 767.0 & 179.9 &  478 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 174.2 & 40.9 & 108.6 & 250.5 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Morningside Heights/Hamilton Heights}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 22.1 & 2.94 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 5.70 & 0.76 & 4.12 & 6.95 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 124.4 & 38.4 & 60 &  188 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 32.0 & 9.88 & 15.4 & 48.4 \\
All Food Chances & 250.3 & 66.7 &  136 &  363 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 64.4 & 17.2 & 35.0 & 93.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Central Harlem}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 22.2 & 3.11 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 6.13 & 0.86 & 4.41 & 7.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 136.8 & 44.7 & 68 &  207 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 37.7 & 12.3 & 18.8 & 57.1 \\
All Food Chances & 249.0 & 71.2 &  130 &  374 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 68.7 & 19.6 & 35.9 & 103.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{East Harlem}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 21.9 & 2.79 & 17 & 26 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 3.52 & 0.45 & 2.73 & 4.18 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 147.1 & 53.5 & 57 &  236 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 23.7 & 8.60 & 9.17 & 38.0 \\
All Food Chances & 249.5 & 79.5 &  114 &  392 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 40.1 & 12.8 & 18.3 & 63.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Washington Heights/Inwood}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 40.3 & 5.06 & 32 & 48 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 5.56 & 0.70 & 4.41 & 6.62 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 269.3 & 78.5 &  140 &  388 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 37.1 & 10.8 & 19.3 & 53.5 \\
All Food Chances & 453.3 & 114.9 &  268 &  646 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 62.5 & 15.8 & 37.0 & 89.1 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Astoria}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 48.8 & 7.19 & 34 & 58 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 3.04 & 0.45 & 2.12 & 3.61 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances &  338 & 72.8 &  202 &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 21.0 & 4.53 & 12.6 & 27.9 \\
All Food Chances & 620.0 & 140.9 &  352 &  858 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 38.6 & 8.78 & 21.9 & 53.4 \\
\midrule 

\emph{Total}  \\*
Healthy Food Chances & 32.0 & 14.0 &  8 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre  & 5.11 & 2.81 & 1.20 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 200.7 & 90.3 & 43 &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 30.7 & 14.7 & 6.93 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances & 361.8 & 187.5 & 80 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per \squarekilometre & 57.0 & 37.6 & 14.0 & 250.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}


\end{document}
```

---

Here is a suggestion on how one could redesign the table. I have removed the repeated information in the first column and combined two rows to one. Additionally, I have used `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to align the numbers relative to their decimal separator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[load=abbr]{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}


{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ p{3cm} S[table-format=3.1]
                     S[table-format=2.2]
                     S[table-format=3.2]
                     S[table-format=2.2]
                     S[table-format=3]
                     S[table-format=2.2]
                     S[table-format=3]
                     S[table-format=2.2]@{}}
\caption{Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods}\\
\toprule
 &\multicolumn{8}{c}{(1)}     \\
Food Chances & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
 &\multicolumn{8}{c}{(1)}     \\
Food Chances & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\scriptsize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.}
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}}  \\*
Healthy  & 43.5 &  3.82 & 9.67 &  0.85 & 25 &  2.1& 61 &  5.35\\
Unhealthy   & 216 &  19.0 & 84.0 &  7.37 & 79 &  6.39 &  354 &  31.1 \\
All  & 365.5 &  32.1 & 121.2 &  10.6 & 159 &  14.0 &  575 &  50.5 \\
\midrule 
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

---

As requested in the comments, I have changed the column header of the first column using `\multirow`:

[image]

```
\toprule
\multirow{2.5}{=}{\raggedright Food Chances by Neighborhood} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre}\\
\midrule
```

Comment: So grateful for everyone's insights!

Comment: Another thought is to change how I'm displaying this information. Following Tufte's suggestion to provide a lot of information I choose this format but maybe you all have another suggestion. I could create 3 separate tables that each show only one type of food chance category. Would that be better?

Comment: @BRB: How you should present your data heavily depends on how you want to discuss them. I have however edited my answer to also include a suggestion how you could reduce the amount of text in the first column.

Comment: Thank you for helping rethink the structure. I have been trying to add the header "Food Chances by Neighborhood" above the column of Mott Haven...but keep failing. What am I doing wrong?  

\multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Food Chances by Neighborhood}  \\
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Max} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} 
& {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre} & {total} & {per \squarekilometre}\\

Comment: @BRB: I have edited my answer to also include the longer column header.

Answer (score 2):

The first row had a wrong number for one of the `\multicolumn`. Anyway, you declared 7 coluns and were using 5, so I reduces their number. I set the 1st column as `X` type, and used  the `S`  column type for the 4 last columns, to align the numbers  by the decimal dot. Also, I added some vertical padding between groups of rows. Last, as the table cannot fit on one page, I loaded `ltables` which brings the advantages of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Note that we don't need the `center` environment: by default, longtables are centred.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\captionsetup{font=bf}
\sisetup{table-format=3.2, table-number-alignment=center, per-mode=symbol}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.6ex}
\begin{tabularx} {12cm} {@{}X SSSS@{}}
\caption{Table 3. Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
& {Mean} & {Std. Dev} & {Min} & {Max }\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\
& {Mean} & {Std. Dev} & {Min} & {Max }\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\em to be continued}
\endfoot
%\\
\bottomrule \addlinespace[1ex]
\scriptsize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.
\endlastfoot
\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 43.5 & 9.67 & 25 & 61 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 3.82 & 0.85 & 2.19 & 5.35 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 216 & 84.0 & 79 & 354 \\
Unhealthy Food Chance\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 19.0 & 7.37 & 6.93 & 31.1 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 365.5 & 121.2 & 159 & 575 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 32.1 & 10.6 & 14.0 & 50.5 \\
\midrule

\emph{Morrisania/East Tremont}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 24.8 & 6.46 & 13 & 34 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 3.09 & 0.80 & 1.62 & 4.23 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 210.8 & 76.4 & 98 & 345 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 26.3 & 9.52 & 12.2 & 43.0 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 325.7 & 107.6 & 163 & 517 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 40.6 & 13.4 & 20.3 & 64.4 \\
\midrule

\emph{Williamsburg/Greenpoint}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 53.2 & 9.10 & 35 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 4.37 & 0.75 & 2.88 & 5.59 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 279.5 & 59.5 & 166 & 359 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 23.0 & 4.88 & 13.6 & 29.5 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 508.9 & 124.4 & 290 & 711 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 41.8 & 10.2 & 23.8 & 58.4 \\
\midrule

\emph{Bedford Stuyvesant} \smallskip\\
Healthy Food Chances & 14.3 & 3.23 & 9 & 22 \\
Healthy Food Chance\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 1.90 & 0.43 & 1.20 & 2.93 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 175.8 & 50.8 & 67 & 252 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 23.4 & 6.77 & 8.92 & 33.6 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 260.6 & 70.4 & 110 & 366 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 34.7 & 9.37 & 14.6 & 48.7 \\
\midrule

\emph{Bushwick}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.8 & 2.50 & 18 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 4.21 & 0.48 & 3.47 & 5.21 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 168.4 & 53.7 & 82 & 259 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 32.5 & 10.4 & 15.8 & 50.0 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 258 & 81.5 & 121 & 398 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 49.8 & 15.7 & 23.4 & 76.8 \\
\midrule

\emph{Sunset Park} \smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 25.7 & 5.39 & 17 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 2.68 & 0.56 & 1.77 & 3.65 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 246.0 & 73.4 & 125 & 369 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 25.7 & 7.66 & 13.0 & 38.5 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 404.9 & 117.9 & 197 & 626 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 42.3 & 12.3 & 20.6 & 65.3 \\
%% \midrule
\pagebreak[4]\emph{North Crown Heights/Prospect Heights}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 38.5 & 6.08 & 24 & 51 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 9.30 & 1.47 & 5.79 & 12.3 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 159.2 & 40.1 & 82 & 222 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 38.4 & 9.68 & 19.8 & 53.6 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 298.2 & 68.8 & 159 & 412 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 72.0 & 16.6 & 38.4 & 99.4 \\
\midrule

\emph{South Crown Heights}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 29.9 & 4.41 & 21 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 7.20 & 1.06 & 5.07 & 8.45 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 125.4 & 24.1 & 76 & 167 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 30.3 & 5.81 & 18.3 & 40.3 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 229.9 & 45.6 & 130 & 309 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 55.5 & 11.0 & 31.4 & 74.6 \\
\midrule

\emph{Brownsville/Ocean Hill}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 18.5 & 4.01 & 8 & 23 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 3.75 & 0.81 & 1.63 & 4.67 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 116.3 & 38.8 & 43 & 183 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 23.6 & 7.88 & 8.74 & 37.2 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 185.8 & 53.2 & 80 & 277 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 37.8 & 10.8 & 16.3 & 56.3 \\
\midrule

\emph{Lower East Side/Chinatown}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 54.4 & 6.15 & 41 & 65 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 12.4 & 1.40 & 9.31 & 14.8 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 297.3 & 73.4 & 172 & 406 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 67.5 & 16.7 & 39.1 & 92.2 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 767.0 & 179.9 & 478 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 174.2 & 40.9 & 108.6 & 250.5 \\
\midrule

\emph{Morningside Heights/Hamilton Heights}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.1 & 2.94 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 5.70 & 0.76 & 4.12 & 6.95 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 124.4 & 38.4 & 60 & 188 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 32.0 & 9.88 & 15.4 & 48.4 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 250.3 & 66.7 & 136 & 363 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 64.4 & 17.2 & 35.0 & 93.4 \\
\midrule

\emph{Central Harlem}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.2 & 3.11 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 6.13 & 0.86 & 4.41 & 7.45 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 136.8 & 44.7 & 68 & 207 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 37.7 & 12.3 & 18.8 & 57.1 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 249.0 & 71.2 & 130 & 374 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 68.7 & 19.6 & 35.9 & 103.1 \\
\midrule

\emph{East Harlem}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.9 & 2.79 & 17 & 26 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 3.52 & 0.45 & 2.73 & 4.18 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 147.1 & 53.5 & 57 & 236 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 23.7 & 8.60 & 9.17 & 38.0 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 249.5 & 79.5 & 114 & 392 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 40.1 & 12.8 & 18.3 & 63.1 \\
\midrule

\emph{Washington Heights/Inwood}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 40.3 & 5.06 & 32 & 48 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 5.56 & 0.70 & 4.41 & 6.62 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 269.3 & 78.5 & 140 & 388 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 37.1 & 10.8 & 19.3 & 53.5 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 453.3 & 114.9 & 268 & 646 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 62.5 & 15.8 & 37.0 & 89.1 \\
\midrule

\emph{Astoria}\smallskip \\
Healthy Food Chances & 48.8 & 7.19 & 34 & 58 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 3.04 & 0.45 & 2.12 & 3.61 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 338 & 72.8 & 202 & 448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 21.0 & 4.53 & 12.6 & 27.9 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 620.0 & 140.9 & 352 & 858 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 38.6 & 8.78 & 21.9 & 53.4 \\
\midrule

\emph{Total}\smallskip\\
Healthy Food Chances & 32.0 & 14.0 & 8 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 5.11 & 2.81 & 1.20 & 14.8 \\ \addlinespace
Unhealthy Food Chances & 200.7 & 90.3 & 43 & 448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 30.7 & 14.7 & 6.93 & 92.2 \\ \addlinespace
All Food Chances & 361.8 & 187.5 & 80 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances\,/\,\si{\square\km} & 57.0 & 37.6 & 14.0 & 250.5
\end{tabularx}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Bernard! I like this table a lot. Can you please explain, what is the (1) at the top of the table associated with? And is it possible to remove it or replace with different text?

Comment: Also, when I try the code on my computer the column headers are centered in the middle of the table instead of over the data. How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: The $(1)$ was in your code. As I didn't know what it corresponded to, I didn't touch it. In `\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}` you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: Do you mean you don't obtain the same alignment for the column headers?

Comment: That is correct. The alignment was centered on the entire table. In your helpful example, it was aligned over the 4 columns of the corresponding data.

Comment: Could you post  the exact code you used? (The table may be shortened, provided it reproduces the problem).

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues in your given code, for example:

1. Use `longtable` instead `tabularx` here. `longtable` can span pages, `tabularx` not.
2. In your table you are only using 5 columns, so I reduced it to `{@{} ldddd @{}}`
3. `longtable` needs no `center`, I deleted it.
4. to format the numbers in the table I used `dcolumn` with `\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2}}`
5. I added the missing `&` to mark the empty columns in your part header lines like `\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}  &       &       &      &      \\`.
6. I deleted the wrong `&\multicolumn{4}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{}   \\` because you have only 5 columns and not 9 as you tried to use in this line ...

With the following code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2}} % two decimal numbers


\begin{document}

\textbf{Table 3. Summary Statistics of Food Chances in New York City Gentrifying Neighborhoods} \par \vspace{2ex}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{} ldddd @{}}
  \toprule
    & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
  \midrule 
\endfirsthead
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{table continued} \\
  \midrule 
    & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
  \midrule 
\endhead
\emph{Mott Haven/Hunts Point}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances           & 43.5  & 9.67  & 25   & 61   \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2   & 3.82  & 0.85  & 2.19 & 5.35 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances         & 216   & 84.0  & 79   &  354 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 19.0  & 7.37  & 6.93 & 31.1 \\
All Food Chances               & 365.5 & 121.2 & 159  &  575 \\
All Food Chances per km2       & 32.1  & 10.6  & 14.0 & 50.5 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Morrisania/East Tremont} &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances           & 24.8 & 6.46 & 13 & 34 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2   & 3.09 & 0.80 & 1.62 & 4.23 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances         & 210.8 & 76.4 & 98 &  345 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 26.3 & 9.52 & 12.2 & 43.0 \\
All Food Chances               & 325.7 & 107.6 &  163 &  517 \\
All Food Chances per km2       & 40.6 & 13.4 & 20.3 & 64.4 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Williamsburg/Greenpoint} &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances           & 53.2 & 9.10 & 35 & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2   & 4.37 & 0.75 & 2.88 & 5.59 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances         & 279.5 & 59.5 &  166 &  359 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.0 & 4.88 & 13.6 & 29.5 \\
All Food Chances               & 508.9 & 124.4 &  290 &  711 \\
All Food Chances per km2       & 41.8 & 10.2 & 23.8 & 58.4 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Bedford Stuyvesant}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 14.3 & 3.23 &  9 & 22 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 1.90 & 0.43 & 1.20 & 2.93 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 175.8 & 50.8 & 67 &  252 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.4 & 6.77 & 8.92 & 33.6 \\
All Food Chances & 260.6 & 70.4 &  110 &  366 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 34.7 & 9.37 & 14.6 & 48.7 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Bushwick}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.8 & 2.50 & 18 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 4.21 & 0.48 & 3.47 & 5.21 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 168.4 & 53.7 & 82 &  259 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 32.5 & 10.4 & 15.8 & 50.0 \\
All Food Chances &  258 & 81.5 &  121 &  398 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 49.8 & 15.7 & 23.4 & 76.8 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Sunset Park}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 25.7 & 5.39 & 17 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 2.68 & 0.56 & 1.77 & 3.65 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 246.0 & 73.4 &  125 &  369 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 25.7 & 7.66 & 13.0 & 38.5 \\
All Food Chances & 404.9 & 117.9 &  197 &  626 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 42.3 & 12.3 & 20.6 & 65.3 \\
\midrule 
\emph{North Crown Heights/Prospect Heights}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 38.5 & 6.08 & 24 & 51 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 9.30 & 1.47 & 5.79 & 12.3 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 159.2 & 40.1 & 82 &  222 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 38.4 & 9.68 & 19.8 & 53.6 \\
All Food Chances & 298.2 & 68.8 &  159 &  412 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 72.0 & 16.6 & 38.4 & 99.4 \\
\midrule 
\emph{South Crown Heights}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 29.9 & 4.41 & 21 & 35 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 7.20 & 1.06 & 5.07 & 8.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 125.4 & 24.1 & 76 &  167 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 30.3 & 5.81 & 18.3 & 40.3 \\
All Food Chances & 229.9 & 45.6 &  130 &  309 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 55.5 & 11.0 & 31.4 & 74.6 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Brownsville/Ocean Hill}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 18.5 & 4.01 &  8 & 23 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.75 & 0.81 & 1.63 & 4.67 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 116.3 & 38.8 & 43 &  183 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.6 & 7.88 & 8.74 & 37.2 \\
All Food Chances & 185.8 & 53.2 & 80 &  277 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 37.8 & 10.8 & 16.3 & 56.3 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Lower East Side/Chinatown}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 54.4 & 6.15 & 41 & 65 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 12.4 & 1.40 & 9.31 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 297.3 & 73.4 &  172 &  406 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 67.5 & 16.7 & 39.1 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances & 767.0 & 179.9 &  478 & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 174.2 & 40.9 & 108.6 & 250.5 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Morningside Heights/Hamilton Heights}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.1 & 2.94 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 5.70 & 0.76 & 4.12 & 6.95 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 124.4 & 38.4 & 60 &  188 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 32.0 & 9.88 & 15.4 & 48.4 \\
All Food Chances & 250.3 & 66.7 &  136 &  363 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 64.4 & 17.2 & 35.0 & 93.4 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Central Harlem}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 22.2 & 3.11 & 16 & 27 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 6.13 & 0.86 & 4.41 & 7.45 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 136.8 & 44.7 & 68 &  207 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 37.7 & 12.3 & 18.8 & 57.1 \\
All Food Chances & 249.0 & 71.2 &  130 &  374 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 68.7 & 19.6 & 35.9 & 103.1 \\
\midrule 
\emph{East Harlem}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 21.9 & 2.79 & 17 & 26 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.52 & 0.45 & 2.73 & 4.18 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 147.1 & 53.5 & 57 &  236 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 23.7 & 8.60 & 9.17 & 38.0 \\
All Food Chances & 249.5 & 79.5 &  114 &  392 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 40.1 & 12.8 & 18.3 & 63.1 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Washington Heights/Inwood}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 40.3 & 5.06 & 32 & 48 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 5.56 & 0.70 & 4.41 & 6.62 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances & 269.3 & 78.5 &  140 &  388 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 37.1 & 10.8 & 19.3 & 53.5 \\
All Food Chances & 453.3 & 114.9 &  268 &  646 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 62.5 & 15.8 & 37.0 & 89.1 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Astoria}  &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances & 48.8 & 7.19 & 34 & 58 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2  & 3.04 & 0.45 & 2.12 & 3.61 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances &  338 & 72.8 &  202 &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 21.0 & 4.53 & 12.6 & 27.9 \\
All Food Chances & 620.0 & 140.9 &  352 &  858 \\
All Food Chances per km2 & 38.6 & 8.78 & 21.9 & 53.4 \\
\midrule 
\emph{Total}                   &       &       &      &      \\
Healthy Food Chances           & 32.0  & 14.0  &  8   & 68 \\
Healthy Food Chances per km2   & 5.11  & 2.81  & 1.20 & 14.8 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances         & 200.7 & 90.3  & 43   &  448 \\
Unhealthy Food Chances per km2 & 30.7  & 14.7  & 6.93 & 92.2 \\
All Food Chances               & 361.8 & 187.5 & 80   & 1103 \\
All Food Chances per km2       & 57.0  & 37.6  & 14.0 & 250.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\par\smallskip\noindent\parbox{12cm}{\raggedright \scriptsize \emph{Source}: NETS\_ACS\_032019.dta.}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Again, thank you everyone for your helpful insights.